# Apps Script OnChange not firing when spreadsheet is edited from elsewhere

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-appsheet

So I have a very simple Apps script code that has OnChange trigger, and it fires whenever I edit the spreadsheet, then sends a post request to another server. It works perfectly when I add or remove a row from the spreadsheet, but if the spreadsheet is edited from an API or Appsheet for example, the trigger doesn't get fired, and so does the post request. Any suggestions?

```
function setUpTrigger() {

ScriptApp.newTrigger('logChanges').forSpreadsheet('ID HERE').onChange().create();

}

function logChanges(e) {
const sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetname')

    if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
      var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
      var row = range.getLastRow();

      Utilities.sleep(3000)

      let obj = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).getValues().toString().split(",") // name, email, number

      let data = {
        'name': obj[0],
        'email': obj[1],
        'number': obj[2]
      };

      const params = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'contentType': 'applic`your text`ation/json',
        'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
      }

      let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('url', params)

    }

}
```

I don't really know why it doesn't get fired when I'm not the one who directly changes it. I saw some questions related to Zapier and IFTTT, and the answers suggested changing the trigger from OnEdit to OnChange, but I already have it OnChange and it's not working.

Comment: That won't work and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639180/onchange-trigger-not-firing-when-using-google-drive-api

Comment: @CharlesHan So I make a timer each fixed time interval and see if there are any changes right? How can I implement that? (I'm not really a JS developer or these stuff, so this is new to me, thanks a lot!)

Comment: You can do this by adding a new Time-drive trigger in the UI. The key problem to solve is to make your code detect a new row added via API, e.g. a new column like 'Processed'. A new row will have the value 'No', and the timer trigger will process the row then set it to 'Yes' after the run.

Comment: Pleasure. Let me know if you are stuck, I am happy to help.

Comment: The post referred in the first comment from Jan 20 is very old and refers to changes done by Google API.. An installable on change trigger used to work for AppSheet. What probably not work as you expect are the "getActive" methods another possibilty are that something change due to recent changes in the way that AppScheet and is integrated with Apps Script / Google Sheets.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/39483929/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67223753/1595451